# How to update focus when toggling tags in Awesome WM?

Tags: configuration, window-manager, awesome, focus

How to reproduce:

1. Install `awesome`, `firefox` and `xterm`.
2. Start Awesome WM with [my current configuration](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/a508ac5ef5643a30d9e467603b11d31b807dcbef/.config/awesome/rc.lua). There should now be an XTerm window in the first tag ("shell") and a Firefox window in the second tag ("browser").
3. Move the mouse pointer to the middle of the left half of the screen.
4. Toggle the second tag with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>.

Now the mouse pointer should be on top of the Firefox window, *but the XTerm window is still focused.* Hence the question: **How do I ensure that Awesome WM updates focus when toggling tags?**